# Validate multiple server side `requirefieldvalidator` on Single Button

Tags: vb.net, updatepanel, requiredfieldvalidator

I've wrote the following code... What I want to do is Simply assign all server side validation on single button-**`ADD`**. But Its not working with this code. Also I've used `javascript` `confirm box` and don't want to fire validation on this.

```
<fieldset style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%">
            <legend style="text-align: Left; font-size: medium;"><strong>User Details </strong>
            </legend>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div align="center">
                        <table style="width: auto; max-width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" Text="* Fields are Mandatory." ForeColor="red"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: right">
                                    <strong style="font-size: small">Name<label style="color: Red">*</label>
                                        :</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: left">
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" placeholder="Enter Name" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <div>
                                        <%--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
                                            <ContentTemplate>--%>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Name!"
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Text Only!"
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtName" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                            <%--</ContentTemplate>
                                            <Triggers>
                                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
                                            </Triggers>
                                        </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: right">
                                    <strong style="font-size: small">DOB<label style="color: Red">*</label>
                                        :</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: left">
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDOB" placeholder="e.g.: 28-Oct-1989" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calDOB" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDOB" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy">
                                    </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                                    <div>
                                        <%--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
                                            <ContentTemplate>--%>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorDOB" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter DOB!"
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtDOB"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgeDob" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDOB"
                                                    ErrorMessage="Please enter DOB in dd-mmm-yyyy format" SetFocusOnError="True"
                                                    ValidationExpression="^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4}$"
                                                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                            <%--</ContentTemplate>
                                            <Triggers>
                                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
                                            </Triggers>
                                        </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: right">
                                    <strong style="font-size: small">Age :</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: left">
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAge"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <%--<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAge"></asp:Label>--%>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: right">
                                    <strong style="font-size: small">Group<label style="color: Red">*</label>
                                        :</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: left">
                                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGroup" TabIndex="3">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Value</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Gold</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Silver</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Bronze</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <div>
                                        <%--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
                                            <ContentTemplate>--%>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_ddlGroup" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Select Group"
                                                    ControlToValidate="ddlGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            <%--</ContentTemplate>
                                            <Triggers>
                                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
                                            </Triggers>
                                        </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: Left">
                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkActive" Text="Active" TabIndex="4" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" align="center">
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" Text="ADD" TabIndex="5" OnClientClick="return fnValidate();" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </fieldset>
```

### SERVER SIDE CODE

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Partial Class Test_NET_27
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

#Region "Variables"
    Private VS_Grid As String = "Null"
#End Region

#Region "PageEvents"
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.txtAge.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly")
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Button Event"
    Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim dt_grid As New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Try
            'If Me.txtName.Text = "" Then
            '    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "UpdateSucessScript", "javascript:alert('Please Fill Up All Mandatory(*) Fields!');", True)
            '    Me.txtName.Focus()
            '    Exit Sub
            'ElseIf (Me.txtDOB.Text.ToString.Trim = "") Then
            '    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "UpdateSucessScript", "javascript:alert('Please Fill Up All Mandatory(*) Fields!');", True)
            '    Me.txtDOB.Focus()
            '    Exit Sub
            'ElseIf (Me.ddlGroup.SelectedValue = 0) Then
            '    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "UpdateSucessScript", "javascript:alert('Please Fill Up All Mandatory(*) Fields!');", True)
            '    Me.ddlGroup.Focus()
            '    Exit Sub
            'End If
            Page.Validate()

            If (Me.ViewState(VS_Grid) Is Nothing) Then
                dt_grid.Columns.Add("Name")
                dt_grid.Columns.Add("Group")
                dt_grid.Columns.Add("Active")
                dt_grid.Columns.Add("Age")
                'dt_grid.Columns.Add("Operation")
            Else
                dt_grid = Me.ViewState(VS_Grid)
            End If
            dr = dt_grid.NewRow
            dr("Name") = Me.txtName.Text.ToString.Trim
            dr("Group") = Me.ddlGroup.SelectedItem.Text.ToString.Trim
            dr("Active") = "InActive"
            If Me.chkActive.Checked = True Then
                dr("Active") = "Active"
            End If
            dr("Age") = Me.txtAge.Text.ToString.Trim

            dt_grid.Rows.Add(dr)
            Me.ViewState(VS_Grid) = dt_grid
            If dt_grid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Me.gvDetails.DataSource = dt_grid
                Me.gvDetails.DataBind()
            Else
                Me.gvDetails.EmptyDataText = "No Data Available."
                Me.gvDetails.DataSource = Nothing
                Me.gvDetails.DataBind()
            End If
            fnResetValues()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "GridEvents"
    Protected Sub gvDetails_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvDetails.RowCommand
        Dim index As Integer = e.CommandArgument
        Dim dt_grid As New DataTable
        Try
            dt_grid = Me.ViewState(VS_Grid)
            If dt_grid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                If e.CommandName.ToUpper = "DELETE" Then
                    dt_grid.Rows(index).Delete()

                End If
                dt_grid.AcceptChanges()
                Me.ViewState(VS_Grid) = dt_grid
                Me.gvDetails.DataSource = dt_grid
                Me.gvDetails.DataBind()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

    Protected Sub gvDetails_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvDetails.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            CType(e.Row.FindControl("lnkDelete"), ImageButton).CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex
            CType(e.Row.FindControl("lnkDelete"), ImageButton).CommandName = "DELETE"
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub gvDetails_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles gvDetails.RowDeleting

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "PageMethod"
    <Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
       Public Shared Function GetAge(ByVal dob As String) As String

        Dim dt_jsonData As New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt_jsonData.NewRow
        Dim age As Integer
        Dim jsonString As String = String.Empty
        Try
            age = Math.Floor(DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, DateValue(dob), Now()) / 12)
            dt_jsonData.Columns.Add("age")
            dr("age") = age.ToString.Trim()
            dt_jsonData.Rows.Add(dr)
            If dt_jsonData.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt_jsonData)
            End If
            Return jsonString
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ""
            Exit Function
        End Try
    End Function
#End Region

#Region "Reset Values"
    Public Function fnResetValues() As Boolean
        Me.txtName.Text = ""
        Me.txtDOB.Text = ""
        Me.txtAge.Text = ""
        Me.ddlGroup.SelectedValue = 0
        Me.chkActive.Checked = False
    End Function
#End Region

End Class
```

When I'm clicking on ADD button its not performing server side validation!

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown your Server Side code... It should have a `Page.Validate()` and a `If Page.IsValid` in it

Comment: OK... so after your page.validate which will return true or false you need If Page.IsValid Then .....Run the code that you want to run if validation is true.... End If

Comment: Also... As I have always run validation both client and server side I'm not sure what the results will be. You may need an Else statement which will display an error to the user.

Comment: But my problem is that even if I haven't filled the details of `Gruop`, its not validating on that.

Comment: You don't seem to be checking your validation. You have done a page.Validate. You have not done a If Page.IsValid Then....

If you pop a breakpoint just after Page.Validate and run you will see that page.Validate will equal True if all is OK and False if there is a validation error. Now you need to code what happens in each case. You do not need to specify Group if you want the whole page validated.

Comment: Ok... Group one was just a try. And my main problem is group i.e. Drop down control is not even being validating. Even validation is unsuccessful, ADD button 's event is running successfully!!!